# Book tickets knowing flight numbers

Tags: air-travel, tickets

I'm trying to book a round trip tickets KRR -> SVO -> AMS -> SEA.

I know there is a flight KRR -> SVO departing at 2:30pm however all search engines then end up with results that give me overnight layover in AMS. If I choose later departing flight they do have me staying overnight in SVO but I need to get there earlier in a day.

Any ideas on how I can go about booking the right combination of flights?

Thank you.

Comment: You may find that the connection you desire is illegal, possibly it is too short. If you can give the flight numbers we might be able to some deeper analysis.

Comment: If you know the flight numbers you can call the airline and book direct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not fully understand what you want but in general, https://matrix.itasoftware.com/ has an astonishing amount of flexibility and https://bookwithmatrix.com/ will typically help you booking it. There is no way to avoid overnighting on this route, it would seem. You can overnight in SVO, if that's what you want / need. This is how you search for the route you asked and then tweak the departure time etc on the result screen. If I do not insist on flying through AMS but enter SVO F+ then there are no overnight combinations leaving Krasnodar at 7:20am at latest, transferring in Moscow and then somewhere else -- if I don't want long layovers as well then Paris or London are your choices but you need to leave at 3:35am or 5:30am. I'd personally rather have a longer layover, a 7:20am flight is already too early for me, the 2:45 layover at Los Angeles is not too bad.

[image]

Comment: You can also add that you can force exact flight numbers or maximum layover times using Matrix. This may highlight if a desired route is illegal or not, or if there is a capacity restriction.

Comment: How can I force maximum layover times? When I was looking at their popup with search operators, I didn't see that option. Thank you!

Comment: Look under extension codes. Example: `MAXCONNECT 2:00` sets a maximum connect of two hours. There's `MINCONNECT` too, which I routinely use to set a connection time so long I can sleep inbetween. No ordinary search engine finds those.